# Futurebuilder on flutter web keeps firing when window size changed

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm experimenting with Flutter Web and just encountered an interesting phenomena - one which chewed through my free API calls allowance for a side project but hey ho :)

On window size change, the futurebuilder fires again and reloads. Is this as intended? If so, is there a way to stop it?

```
FutureBuilder(
            future: _fetchMarketData(
                'BOO.XLON,BBOX.XLON,DGE.XLON,GROW.XLON,GSK.XLON,IBM,IEM.XLON,NIO,ULVR.XLON'),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              print('Building');
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                List<MarketData> md = snapshot.data;

                List<MarketData> _boo =
                    md.where((md) => md.symbol == 'BOO.XLON').toList();

                List<MarketData> _dge =
                    md.where((md) => md.symbol == 'DGE.XLON').toList();

                List<MarketData> _grow =
                    md.where((md) => md.symbol == 'GROW.XLON').toList();

                List<MarketData> _gsk =
                    md.where((md) => md.symbol == 'GSK.XLON').toList();

                List<MarketData> _iem =
                    md.where((md) => md.symbol == 'IEM.XLON').toList();

                List<MarketData> _tri =
                    md.where((md) => md.symbol == 'BBOX.XLON').toList();

                List<MarketData> _ibm =
                    md.where((md) => md.symbol == 'IBM').toList();

                List<MarketData> _nio =
                    md.where((md) => md.symbol == 'NIO').toList();

                List<MarketData> _ulvr =
                    md.where((md) => md.symbol == 'ULVR.XLON').toList();

                List<MarketData> combinedData = [
                  _boo[0],
                  _dge[0],
                  _grow[0],
                  _gsk[0],
                  _tri[0],
                  _ibm[0],
                  _iem[0],
                  _nio[0],
                  _ulvr[0],
                ];

                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Text(
                          '${combinedData[index].symbol} - HIGH ${combinedData[index].high}, LOW ${combinedData[index].low}');
                    },
                    itemCount: combinedData.length,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                  ),
                );
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text(
                    'Could not fetch data :-/ ${snapshot.error.toString()}');
              } else {
                return Text('Fetching!');
              }
            })
```

Comment: With the given information its not possible to guess the cause. Could you give little more details like what is the parent widget of this `FutureBuilder`. Or if you could provide a MRE maybe in dartpad we can check.:)

Comment: Actually, I'm asking the wrong question - apparently the widget tree rebuilds on window resize which is triggering the futurebuilder to rebuild constantly

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that is intentional... or at least you built it that way.

If you do this:

```
future: _fetchMarketData()
```

Then every time the build function is called, a new Future is generated.

What you need to do is have a variable of type `Future<>` that you set *once*, preferably in `initState`, and then give this variable to your `FutureBuilder`. This way, even when your build function is called multiple times, it still has the one Future it waits for.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this issue earlier but in the latest beta this issue doesn't seem to occur. Make sure you're updated to latest version on beta channel and try again.

Comment: Which version of the beta are you on? I'm running Flutter 1.23.0-18.1.pre • channel beta

Comment: Using the same @kenwen

Answer (score 0):

In addition to fetching my future in initState(), I also did a conditional fetch in didUpdateWidget(). This worked for my case.